# how to fix hyper v issue

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, hyper-v

While running vagrant up --provision, getting following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues that I have occasionally struggled with in Hyper-V is that of time synchronization. Right now, for example, the time on my Windows 10 desktop that I am using to write this article is 9:37 p.m. However, the Hyper-V host that I am watching on another monitor is displaying a time of 9:33 p.m.

On the surface, a few minutes of clock skew might seem like a non-issue. However, there are several reasons why the differing clocks are problematic.

One such reason is that the Kerberos protocol, which is heavily used by the Windows operating system, is time-sensitive. If two systems' clocks are more than a few minutes out of sync with one another, it can cause Kerberos to stop working.

Another reason why clock skew is such a big deal is because multi-tier applications often span multiple Hyper-V hosts. A database server might, for instance, reside on one host, while a Web front end exists on another host, possibly even within a different host cluster.

Comment: but this obviously is a Linux container, so how this should be the cause? while `NTP` could prevent such issues... but it doesn't even get that far, as the screenshot shows.

Comment: Yes, that issue mentioned by Norton might occur after VM gets created and run. However, in my case, VM itself is not getting created.

Answer (score 0):

when looking at [start_vm.ps1](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/providers/hyperv/scripts/start_vm.ps1), it seems to use command [Start-VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/start-vm?view=win10-ps).

and since this seems to be Windows, the [Event Viewer](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2018/01/23/looking-at-the-hyper-v-event-log-january-2018-edition/) might tell why it crashes.

I'd have a look at event channel `Hyper-V-Config` or `Hyper-V-Worker`.

command [Test-VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/test-vhd?view=win10-ps) might also be worth a try.

Comment: Where can I see event-log?

Comment: in the management console; it's `eventvwr.msc`. that being told by a Linux user :)

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: it's still `eventvwr.msc`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting event log and do not understand it.

[image]